# Solar cell efficiency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, voltage, solar-cells

What is the relation between open circuit voltage and efficiency of the solar cell?

Let say that I include the graph of Voc and efficiency in my result. How to relate them both? Thanks :)

Comment: The open circuit voltage is meaningless for the efficiency, as there is no power being generated by an unloaded cell. As we load the cell with ever higher current (up to the short circuit current), an increasing amount of power will be generated, up to a point where the product of voltage and current is maximal, beyond that the voltage will break down faster than the current will increase and the efficiency will go down, again. At the short circuit current the efficiency of the cell is zero, yet again. The solar controller in the system has to actively find the point of highest efficiency.

Comment: Did you try googling it? http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Following from CuriousOne's implied answer in his comment, I looked up an equivalent circuit model of the solar cell. I took it from the commercial [website of Omicron Lab](https://www.omicron-lab.com/fileadmin/assets/application_notes/SolarCell/App_Note_Solar_Impedance_V1_2.pdf) (a manufacturer of vector network analyzers), so it seems reasonable, but I'm not experienced in modelling solar cells. The general method you will have to follow is to find out and consider an equivalent circuit model as I am doing below.

[image: Solar Cell Model]

We'll forget about the capacitor, since we only want to find the steady state efficiency (a capacitor is an open circuit at DC). To work out the energy efficiency, we think of a load's being connected to the output. Let's say the load's resistance is $R_L$. Then the current through the load is:

$$I_L=I_{mod} \,\frac{(R_s + R_L)^{-1}}{(R_s + R_L)^{-1} + R_P^{-1}}$$

(currents through parallel elements divide pro rata with the *conductances* of the parallel paths). Likewise, the current through the parallel source resistor $R_P$ is:

$$I_P=I_{mod} \,\frac{R_P^{-1}}{(R_s + R_L)^{-1} + R_P^{-1}}$$

and now you should be able to work out the ratio of the power delivered to the load to the total power dissipated as

$$\eta=\frac{I_L^2\,R_L}{I_L^2\,(R_L+R_s) + I_P^2 R_P}$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a diode symbol in parallel with $I_{mod}$, $C_p$, and $R_p$?  After all, a silicon PV cell _is_ a PN diode.